# Using Root Relative URLS instead of Absolute to solve Wordpress Migration Problem

Tags: wordpress, url, local, relative-path, absolute-path

I'd like to solve the problem of not needing to change all links in a project when preparing to migrate from local to live. I'd like to avoid absolute urls altogether, and since relative urls on Wordpress doesn't look like a good way to go. I'd like to strictly use root relative links.

My current local Ampps Apache server is set up so that each Wordpress site has its own subdirectory. So I have root relative links that look like these:

`/wp-pachira/wp-content/themes/pachira/resources/assets/scripts/pachira-critical.js
/wp-pachira/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/logo_1.3-05-01-01.svg`

What I need is have all links without the `wp-pachira` subdirectory, like so:

`/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/logo_1.3-05-01-01.svg`

In attempt to solve this problem, I've tried to add a local domain called pachira.local in Ampps, making sure to modify my Windows hosts file. The domain works, as it points to my local ip as it should, but it still recognizes only the links with the /wp-pachira/ subdirectory.

I've also tried a different method of directly modifying the Apache config file, but no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the URLs in your WordPress settings? WordPress Address and Site Address.

Comment: Yes. They include the subdirectory.